if I know everything about a closed surface, how can I calculate the volume it bounds
let $\Gamma \hookrightarrow M$ be a embedded compact submanifold of codimension one, and it bounds a regular domain of $M$, if I know the exterior differential, christoffel symbols, and curvature forms of $\Gamma$ and $M$, and also the second fundamental forms of the embedding, But the explicit expression for the embedding is unknown. How can I calculate the volume it bounds?

That might be enough information to reconstruct the embedding.

I doubt that this works in general. The example I give is in too low dimension to really make sense, but I think something similar can be cooked up in higher dimensions. Imagine a cylinder and smoothly close one end by some kind of cap. Let $\Gamma$ be a curve around the cylinder. Then you can move $\Gamma$ up and down the cylinder without changing anything about the embedding, but the enclose area changes. (More technically, translations along the cylinder a local isometries and therefore preserve all embedding data. But they are not restrictions of global isometries because of the cap.)

CORRECTION: This answer works only if $M$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the flat metric.
The embedding map $u: \Gamma \rightarrow M$ satisfies, with respect to local coordinates on $\Gamma$ and $M$,  the equation $$\partial^2_{jk}u^a = A^i_{jk}\partial_iu^a - B^a_{bc}\partial_ju^b\partial_ku^c + S_{jk}\nu^a(\partial_1u, \cdots, \partial_nu), $$ where $A^i_{jk}$ are the Christoffel symbols on $M$, $B^a_{jk}$ are the Christoffel symbols on $M$, $S_{jk}$ is the second fundamental form, and $\nu(\partial_1u, \dots, \partial_nu)$ is the unit normal such tha at each point on $\Gamma$, $$(\partial_1u, \dots, \partial_nu,\nu)$$ is a positively oriented basis of tangent vectors. This is an overdetermined system of PDEs. The Gauss and Codazzi-Mainardi equations imply that it is integrable. It follows that there is a unique solution up to rotation and translation. This reduces your question to: Suppose you know how $\Gamma$ is embedded in $M$. How can you calculate the volume enclosed by $\Gamma$?

The argument with the Gauss-Codazzi equations certainly works for embeddings into $\mathbb R^n$, but I do not see how to make sense of it in the case of an embedding into a curved manifold (unless for specific cases of constant curvature). Also the statement ofn uniquess only makes sense for $\mathbb R^n$ (and I am not sure whether some uniqueness statment is available in general).

@AndreasCap, you are correct. I will edit my answer accordingly. Thanks.
